# Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS: ERROR: Could not find 'wxe_driver.so'

Tags: erlang, observers, ubuntu-20.04

```
maxximiliann@Maxximiliann:$ iex -S mix
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.7.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [

Interactive Elixir (1.10.3) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)


iex(1)> :observer.start

12:45:30.511 [error] ERROR: Could not find 'wxe_driver.so' in: /home/maxximiliann/.asdf/installs/erlang/22.3.3/lib/wx-1.9/priv

{:error,
{{:load_driver, 'No driver found'},
[ 
{:wxe_server, :start, 1, [file: 'wxe_server.erl', line: 65]},
{:wx, :new, 1, [file: 'wx.erl', line: 115]},
{:observer_wx, :init, 1, [file: 'observer_wx.erl', line: 107]},
{:wx_object, :init_it, 6, [file: 'wx_object.erl', line: 372]},
{:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 249]}
]}}
```

[These](https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/erlang-wx) instructions were followed to install `erlang-wx` on this Ubuntu machine:

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-48-generic
Architecture: x86-64
```

What else is required to get `observer` to run?

Answer (score 4):

The `erlang-wx` package is only used by the Erlang installed through Ubuntu packages, but yours was built with asdf.  When you asked asdf to build Erlang, it presumably printed this:

```
 * wx             : wxWidgets not found, wx will NOT be usable
```

To fix that, install the package `libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev`, and then remove and reinstall the asdf Erlang installation.

Answer (score 1):

Resharing what solved my problem: [:observer.start is not working on Ubuntu](https://elixirforum.com/t/observer-start-is-not-working-on-ubuntu/6018/29?u=skedaddl3) answer is from [rogerweb](https://elixirforum.com/u/rogerweb)

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS Focal
- Elixir: 1.13.0
- Erlang/OTP 25 [erts-13.0.3]

Solution:

`sudo apt install libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-0v5`